# Pandas drop duplicates within groupby

Tags: python, pandas

This is my csv look like,

```
name, cuisine, review
A, Chinese, this
A, Indian, is
B, Indian, an
B, Indian, example
B, French, thank
C, French, you
```

I trying to count how many times the diff kind of cuisines appear by name. This is what I should be getting

```
Cuisine, Count
Chinese, 1
Indian, 2
French, 2
```

But as you can see there are duplicates within the name e.g. B so I try to drop_duplicates but I can't. I use

```
df.groupby('name')['cuisine'].drop_duplicates()
```

and it says series groupby object cannot.

Somehow I need to apply value_counts() to get the number of occurrences of the cuisine word but the duplicates thing is hindering. Any idea how I can get this in pandas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `groupby` and `nunique`:

```
df.groupby('cuisine', sort=False).name.nunique().to_frame('count')

         count
cuisine       
Chinese      1
Indian       2
French       2
```

Will return the count of unique items per group.

Answer (score 2):

Using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.name,df.cuisine).ne(0).sum()
Out[550]: 
cuisine
 Chinese    1
 French     2
 Indian     2
dtype: int64
```